# Facebook SDK not working with Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, typescript, sdk

I'm trying to simply make a post to facebook using Javascript/Typescript.

Nothing is working however.

This is my typescript code:

```
(window as any). //couldn't get code to compile without this...

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'MY API KEY',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.7'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

declare var FB:any;
// Only works after `FB.init` is called
function myFacebookLogin() {
    FB.login(function(){
        // Note: The call will only work if you accept the permission request
        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'Hello, world!'});
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<script src="./js/main.js"></script>     

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<button onclick="myFacebookLogin()">Login with Facebook</button>    
<div id="status">
</div>    
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

I got the above code from the facebook developer site.

Comment: Can be more specific?  What's not working?

Comment: I believe there is meant to be a pop up asking you to sign in, but nothing happens at all when opening the html in browser.

Comment: did you check the browser console? that´s the first thing you need to do, always.

Comment: btw, check out this article: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to cast `window` to `any`, you can do this:

```
interface Window {
    fbAsyncInit: () => void;
}
```

Then this should work:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'MY API KEY',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.7'
    });
};
```

As for the login, according to [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.7) you are missing the part which handles the error. The function that you pass to `FB.login` receives a `response` with which you can check the status:

```
function myFacebookLogin() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { 
                message: 'Hello, world!'
            });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
}
```

Now you'll know if the login failed.

Comment: Still getting nothing when I click "Login with Facebook".

Comment: There's nothing in the console?